# How to reflect a Static Public Method with Parameter passed by reference, for example Int32.TryParse

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to write a generic extension method targeting .Net 4.5. I want to test a type to see if TryParse is defined in the class. If yes, invoke the TryParse method at runtime.

Here is my implemenation.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ExtentionMethodPractises
{
    static public class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static T ParseOrDefault<T>(this T targetType, string source) where T : new()
        {
            if (targetType.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public).Any(methodInfo => methodInfo.Name == "TryParse"))
            {
                var result = new T();

                var parameterTypes = new Type[] {source.GetType(), targetType.GetType()};

                var parameterModifier = new ParameterModifier(2);
                parameterModifier[0] = false;
                parameterModifier[1] = true;

                var tryParseMethod = targetType.GetType().GetMethod("TryParse", parameterTypes, new ParameterModifier[] { parameterModifier});

                tryParseMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {source, result});

                return result;
            }

            return new T();
        }
    }
}
```

I tested my extension method with `System.UInt16` which has TryParse methods. I got a nullref on the `tryParseMethod` after reflection.

I implemented a dummy test class `ReflectorTarget` to test my extension method. I got a null reference too. It seems that the reflector is incapable of search methods has pass-by-reference parameter(s).

```
namespace ExtentionMethodPractises
{
    public class ReflectorTarget
    {
        public static bool TryParse(string source, out ReflectorTarget output)
        {
            output = new ReflectorTarget();
            return true;
        }

        public static bool TryParse(string source, bool isReally, out ReflectorTarget output)
        {
            output = new ReflectorTarget();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, I changed my dummy test class implementation as follows. Suddenly, the reflector will pick up the `TryParse` method at runtime. All I did is change the second parameter from a pass-by-reference parameter to a normal parameter.

```
namespace ExtentionMethodPractises
{
    public class ReflectorTarget
    {
        public static bool TryParse(string source, ReflectorTarget output)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public static bool TryParse(string source, bool isReally, out ReflectorTarget output)
        {
            output = new ReflectorTarget();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Question: How do I reflect a method (static/non-static) that has a pass-by-reference parameter in C#? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using the overload that takes `ParameterModifiers`? Quote from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wty12hw3.aspx): To be only used when calling through COM interop, and only parameters that are passed by reference are handled. The default binder does not process this parameter.

Comment: You are right. It didn't make sense to me as well. At that time, it was the only way I knew to make a parameter attributed with passing-by-reference.I will try the solution given by Damien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
namespace ExtentionMethodPractises
{
    static public class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static T ParseOrDefault<T>(this T targetType, string source)
            where T : new()
        {
            if (targetType.GetType()
                .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public)
                .Any(methodInfo => methodInfo.Name == "TryParse"))
            {
                var result = new T();

                var parameterTypes = new Type[] {source.GetType(),

                          //Key change here
                          targetType.GetType().MakeByRefType()};

                var tryParseMethod = targetType.GetType()
                    .GetMethod("TryParse", parameterTypes);

                tryParseMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {source, result});

                return result;
            }

            return new T();
        }
    }
}
```

see [`MakeByRefType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makebyreftype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Returns a [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object that represents the current type when passed as a **ref** parameter (**ByRef** parameter in Visual Basic).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now I know how to make a RefType. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
   tryParseMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {source, result});
```

Damien got you unblocked on passing the correct type, but you still need to invoke the method correctly.  A method that takes a *ref* argument will update the value in the passed object[], it is not going to modify your *result* variable.  And you are interested in the return value of this method.  Also notable is that ParameterModifier is actually ignored for .NET methods.  Which collapses your method down to:

```
public static T ParseOrDefault<T>(this T targetType, string source) where T : new() {
    var parameterTypes = new Type[] { source.GetType(), targetType.GetType().MakeByRefType() };
    var tryParseMethod = targetType.GetType().GetMethod("TryParse", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, parameterTypes, null);
    if (tryParseMethod != null) {
        var args = new object[] { source, null };
        var retval = (bool)tryParseMethod.Invoke(null, args);
        if (retval) return (T)args[1];
    }
    return new T();
}
```

Comment: Right on the spot. It puzzles me that result is not updated after invoking the method. Eventually, I came up with the same solution. But  why result didnt get updated? Shouldnt result be passed by reference to the TryParse method?

Comment: That would take a reference to a reference to an object :)